# Sharepoint online search search results show files that user has with no permission

Tags: sharepoint

I am working on Sharepoint Online. I have a requirement that when a user has no permission to a file, he/she still can see file in search result, but no permission to open the file.
I know there is security trimming in sharepoint search. But is it possible to achieve my requirement?

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As Ondrej has said this isn't possible via the OOTB search functionality and this is by design.

If you wanted to be able to see all information returned by search you would need to write something custom and impersonate a user who does have access to the document.

[Impersonation of User in office 365/SharePoint online](http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/runwithelevatedprivileges-in-sharepoint-online-office-365/)

I'd only do the above in exceptional circumstances.

I would be questioning why you want someone to be able to see something they do not have access to read.

Cheers

Truez

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The business requirement is that each team has its own Document Library. Team member can search for resources. If the search result find a useful resource but it does not belong to the person, the person can further ask the owner to grand access to the file.

Comment: I'd put the responsibility on the content owner to make sure people that the content would be relevant to have at least ready access. Unless you have a solid naming convention it will be hard for your users to definitely know that the document will be useful to them.